# error when accessing worklight server deployed on tomcat

Tags: deployment, unique, ibm-mobilefirst

I deploy the war file and adapter file to the tomcat,everything is fine,but when I try access the worklight server,the request is

> [http://10.30.3.11:8080/nantian/apps/services/api/attendance/android/query]

and the logcat appear this error

> [http://10.30.3.11:8080/nantian/apps/services/api/attendance/android/query]failure. state: 500, response:
>    The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.[http://10.30.3.11:8080/nantian/apps/services/api/attendance/android/query]Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

and the tomcat appear the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unique constrain: found 2 beans implementing inteface com.worklight.server.report.api.GadgetReportsService (in 4 spring application contexts).
>       at com.worklight.server.bundle.api.ServiceManager.getServiceConsumer(ServiceManager.java:133)
>       at com.worklight.core.bundle.CoreServiceManager.getGadgetsReportService(CoreServiceManager.java:47)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.logLoginActivity(AuthenticationContext.java:337)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:495)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:396)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:373)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:63)
>       at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:162)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I am sure that I just deploy one war file to the tomcat,but I have try deploying the war file again and again to test the app,Of course,undeploy the file before I deploy it.and the worklight server is 5.0.5,mysql 5.1.47,tomcat 7.0.37.Any help?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an installation using IBM Installation Mananger?
If you've used it to install Worklight on Tomcat then it has also deployed a worklight.war file during installation.

Make sure you undeploy this .war file via the Tomcat Manager view (typically `http://localhost:8080/manager`). I would also go to the file system and make sure no other files remain (the .war file, worklight.home, ...).

Next, deploy your own .war file (probably nantian.war or alike).

Comment: thanks for answer so fast,But I can't undeploy the worklight.war file via the Tomcat Manager view,the undeploy button is disabled.so I go to the /webapps path and delete the worklight.jar and the /worklight file ,the tomcat start with some error.However,I can access the worklight server correct,does it ok?

Comment: No. Don't delete any worklight .jar files...! but if you say that you can now access http://localhost:8080/nantian/console then it seems your problem was resolved?

Comment: oh,that's a mistake,what I mean is worklight.war file and the /worklight file under the /webapps,and I alse delete the /worklight.home under the /bin and /worklight under the /work/Catalina/localhost,however when I start the tomcat,it still get some error which point that it can't find the /worklight path ,but yes,I can access the link now.

Comment: If your issue is resolved please mark this question as Answered. Thanks.