# Failed to deploy worklight adapter in Worklight

Tags: deployment, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8

When deploying the [BPM project](http://bpmwiki.blueworkslive.com/display/samples/Mobile+BPM+%28Worklight+sample%29) in a development environment, everything works. However, when trying to move the project to the WAS application server, the adapter deployment fails (.war and .wlapp deployment passes successfully):

```
Failed to deploy adapter 'BPMAdapter.adapter'. : Procedure 'getRest' in adapter 'BPMAdapter' requires security test 'BPMAdapter-securityTest' which is not defined in authenticationConfig.xml.
```

We've verified the security test exists in authenticationConfig.xml, here's the portion of the tests, so it is, in fact present:

```
<securityTests>
    <customSecurityTest name="BPMAdapter-securityTest">
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="BPMAuthRealm"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
    <webSecurityTest name="BPMApp-web-securityTest">
        <testUser realm="BPMAuthRealm"/>
    </webSecurityTest>
    <mobileSecurityTest name="BPMApp-strong-mobile-securityTest">
        <testUser realm="BPMAuthRealm"/>
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
    <mobileSecurityTest name="BPMApp-mobile-securityTest">
        <testUser realm="BPMAuthRealm"/>
    </mobileSecurityTest>
</securityTests>
```

These are the steps we've taken:

Testing server: Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter
Database: DB2 10.1
Application Server: WAS 8.0.0.3 ND

1. Installed Worklight Server Enterprise 5.0.5 with DB2 databases successfully. (Worklight is working at: `http://internal:9082`
2. Installed in the server (for the sake of not having problems with JDBC during build) Worklight Studio Enterprise 5.0.5 successfully.
3. Imported the project into a new workspace inside Studio.
4. Deployed worklight adapter BPMAdapter.xml successfully.
5. Right click on the app (BPMApp) and "Build All and Deploy" successfully.
6. Opened `http://internalIP:8080/console` (Development Jetty based worklight console) to see if the application deployed, and indeed it's shown in the list (Both the apps and the adapter).
7. Tested with "Preview as common resources" to verify the application works, success.

   Now we proceed to make the adjustments to the files needed for WAS deployment:
8. Changed the  in the application-descriptor.xml file from
   `http://${local.IPAddress}:8080` to `http://internalIP:9082/worklight` (this example shows the same approach http://goo.gl/xbynL)
9. At that point we open the bin dir and copy to a folder in the desktop all the *.wlapp files and the BPMAdapter.adapter file.
10. Now we make the changes in the worklight.properties file:

    publicWorkLightHostname=the operational hostname for the worklight server
    publicWorkLightProtocol=http
    publicWorkLightPort=9082
    publicWorkLightContext=/worklight
    wl.db.jndi.name=jdbc/WorklightDS
    wl.db.type=DB2
    wl.db.url=jdbc:db2:Worklight
    wl.db.username=wluser
    wl.db.password=correctpassword
    wl.reports.db.jndi.name=jdbc/WorklightReportsDS
    wl.reports.db.type=${wl.db.type}
    wl.reports.db.url=${wl.db.url}
    wl.reports.db.username=${wl.db.username}
    wl.reports.db.password=${wl.db.password}
11. Saved the worklight.properties and immediately the *.war is regenerated, we copy the *.war to the deployment folder for later upload to WAS.
12. Create in WAS the Enterprise application according to: (Infocenter for WL 5.0.5 - Deploying a customization .war file to WebSphere Application Server Full Profile) making sure that In the "Class loader order" pane, click Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last) and In the modules section the "Class loader order" pane, click Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last).
    WAR upload and start-up is successful.
13. With the .war uploaded (context root BPMWorklight) we go in the browser to `http://internalIP:9082/BPMWorklight/console/#catalog` 
    and upload the BPMApp-all.wlapp (we don't upload the other three iPhone, android or common, just the -all.wlapp) the upload is successful.
14. We proceed to upload in `http://internalIP:9082/BPMWorklight/console/#catalog` 
    the adapter BPMAdapter.adapter, we get the error "Failed to deploy adapter 'BPMAdapter.adapter'. : Procedure 'getRest' in adapter 'BPMAdapter' requires security test 'BPMAdapter-securityTest' which is not defined in authenticationConfig.xml."

Comment: Make sure the that the authenticationConfig.xml inside the updated .war file indeed has the supposedly missing securityTest.

Comment: Idan, yes! just verified the tests are in the deployed .war, should we look for something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here: [Failed deploying application using Worklight Console: "Failed to deploy application <appName>.wlapp'. : ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601719/failed-deploying-application-using-worklight-console-failed-to-deploy-applicat)

Make sure that the Worklight Server version that is installed on WebSphere matches that of the Worklight Studio Eclipse plug-in used to create the .war, .wlapps and .adapter files.

In addition, make sure that:

1. you use the same context root ("BPMWorklight") for all:

   - in application-descriptor.xml
   - in worklight.properties
   - name of the .war file
2. you have removed the previous .war installed by default by the Worklight installation on WAS

I am getting the feeling that you have several Worklight .war files deployed and they are somehow using the wrong .war, thus not finding/using the correct authenticationConfig.xml, which could explain not finding the securityTest.

In Worklight 5.0.x, there should be only 1 Worklight .war file at a time.

Comment: Idan, we have plugin version 5.0.5.1 and server version 5.0.5 (There's no 5.0.5.1 server that we know of) the only thing would be upgrade both server and plugin to 5.0.6 but we are still unable to do so because we still use a previous version of Cordova.

Comment: Idan, we were able to find a plugin version 5.0.5 with the MAC IWS.
We rebuilt the .war, reinstalled it in the server and reloaded the BPMApp-all.wlapp, the wlapp uploads ok. When we try to upload the .adapter we now simply get: "Failed to deploy adapter 'BPMAdapter.adapter'. : ERROR"
Your thoughts are badly needed and greatly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: This error is exactly the same error as I described in my list in the Answer. You must make sure that the version of Worklight Server and Worklight Studio are the same.

Comment: Idan these are our versions:
Server version: 5.0.5.20121130-0919
WorklightStudio plugin: 5.0.5.20121130-0158

Are they the same? I guess they are... can you please confirm?

Comment: From a first glanse, no, they are not... are you a customer of IBM, or an IBMer?

Comment: See my answer in this question, download 5.0.5 again. Make sure the versions match. I think it will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649252/where-can-i-find-worklight-studio-plug-in-for-ibm-worklight-v5-0-0-3/

Comment: Idan, actively working on the problem. Still not done reinstalling Server and Studio 5.0.5 hopefully will be done by tomorrow and be back with results. Thanks!

Comment: Idan, we installed server 5.0.5 and studio 5.0.5 from scratch and new DBs (DB2) and WAS. The error persists after building successfully. When we try to publish the adapter: Failed to deploy adapter 'BPMAdapter.adapter'. : "Procedure 'getRest' in adapter 'BPMAdapter' requires security test 'BPMAdapter-securityTest' which is not defined in authenticationConfig.xml." We still have not deployed the war tough, per your instructions. Once we get both the adapter and the wlapp we will move to the war and finally the ipa. Please let us know as we are REALLY, really stuck... Thanks again!

Comment: If you did not deploy the .war file belonging to the BPM project, how do you expect it to recognize anything related to it? You must first deploy the .war file and only then any .wlapp or .adapter files

Comment: Idan, just repeated the procedure. First the .war (with the WAS and DB2 properties) then the .wlapp and .adapter (built with the jetty properties). The war uploaded without a problem. The .wlapp perfect too, the .adapter generates this error: "Failed to deploy adapter 'BPMAdapter.adapter'. : Procedure 'getRest' in adapter 'BPMAdapter' requires security test 'BPMAdapter-securityTest' which is not defined in authenticationConfig.xml." Please advice...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nechavarria, I still think the problem is in the versioning. I would like you to edit the question with the steps you've taken. All of them...

Comment: Hello Idan! Well, I think we had a problem with the "context-root" as you suggested. Now the BPMAdapter.adapter deploys, the BPMApp-all.wlapp deploys and the BPMWorklight.war deploys. However we get a Fail app screen when we try to run the application as the "Preview as Common Resources". We should arrive at a user login screen but after checking the firebug error, this is what we get:401 Unauthorized:/*-secure-{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"h1rfkdeih0dp1hho9v2i26civ7"}}}*/ and then finally a 500 Error: "errorMsg":"Unique constrain: found 2 beans implementing inteface.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on what might be the issue? Thanks a lot Idan!

Comment: "found 2 beans implementing interface" usually means that there are several Worklight .war files deployed. There should be only one .war file - the one you are currently using.

Comment: Checking your answer to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893587/error-when-accessing-worklight-server-deployed-on-tomcat
Will keep you posted...

Comment: Idan, finally!! You were right on all your hunches... The only thing that was not clear to me was that the Worklight Console app installed in the WAS was actually another version of worklight.war and that was the origin of the final error. Now everything is working correctly... heading to upload .ipa now!....Thanks so much Idan for your help and guidance!!

Comment: I am pleased this saga has come to an end. Please mark as Answered and up-vote. :)