# IBM Worklight 5.0.5 - Realm is not defined in authenticationConfig.xml

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

Here is the error I receive from our WebSphere application server liberty profile running Worklight Server:

`defaultOptions:onFailure Procedure invocation error. Runtime: The realm 'SingleStepAuthRealm' is not defined in authenticationConfig.xml.`

This runs fine on my local server.

I have rebuilt and deployed the server customization WAR file to the server, and restarted it.

Could this be because the version of the remote server does not match up with the version of my local server? Local server version is: 5.0.5.20121129-1027

Here is my authenticationConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

        <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
             5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2012. All Rights Reserved.
             US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
             disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->  

    <!-- Uncomment the next element to protect the worklight console -->
    <!-- <staticResources>
        <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="WorklightConsole">
            <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
        </resource>
    </staticResources> -->

   <!--  Sample security tests  
         Even if not used there will be some default  webSecurityTest and mobileSecurityTest 
         Attention: if using <testAppAuthenticity/> test below ,<publicSigningKey> element must be added to application-descriptor.xml as well. -->   
         
    <!-- <securityTests>
        
        <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
            <testAppAuthenticity/> 
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
        </mobileSecurityTest>

        <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
            <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/>
        </webSecurityTest>

        <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        
        <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
            <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
        </customSecurityTest>

    </securityTests> -->
    
    <realms>
          <realm name="SingleStepAuthRealm" loginModule="SingleStepAuthLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-function" value="SingleStepAuthAdapter.onAuthRequired" />
            <parameter name="logout-function" value="SingleStepAuthAdapter.onLogout" />
          </realm>
        
        <!-- For websphere -->
        <!-- realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
            <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
            <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
        </realm -->
    </realms>

    <loginModules>
          <loginModule name="SingleStepAuthLoginModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
          </loginModule>
        
        <!-- For websphere -->
        <!-- loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
        </loginModule -->
    </loginModules>

</tns:loginConfiguration>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Orlando's answer, I was able to discern the server versions:
Server version: 5.0.5.20121130-0919
Local version: 5.0.5.20121129-1027

The version (probably the build number, not sure how WL versions work) is different; however, I suspect that minor version mismatch is not the issue.

Here is what I have tried so far to debug this issue:

1. I followed the steps in the worklight documentation to build and upload my server   customization file to the proper directory on the server.

   You can find those steps [in this IC article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_for_building_and_dep.html) under the heading "Deploying a project".
2. I opened up the WAR file and noticed that the authenticationConfig.xml is not in there! So, I figured I would manually push the XML up into the same folder that it resides in on my local server. In my case,this directory is:
   /opt/IBM/Worklight/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklightServer/worklight.home/app_name/conf
3. I figured it might have been a permissions issue, so I set +rwx on the file. Still no dice.
4. Maybe its looking for the other files that are in that directory on my local server? I uploaded all of them and tried the permissions again. No luck.
5. I also restarted the server after each one of these steps (and in the case of step 4, restarted it twice, once with default perms and once with full perms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestion [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683749/failed-to-deploy-worklight-adapter-in-worklight)?

Basically:

How many .war files do you have deployed in your application server? 
In Worklight 5 there can be only 1. Make sure this is the case.

Comment: I tried removing the other war files and running the server from app_name.war, but I get an error about the Worklight Project not being initialized. Later today or Monday I am going to go back through the whole process and double check everything. It seems like this is the solution (I probably just missed something obvious in the configuration), and I will accept the answer once I've got it working.

Comment: I wasn't ever able to get this solved unfortunately. However, we upgraded to Worklight 6 and this problem went away. I will accept this answer because it still seems like the most likely solution.

Answer (score 3):

Start by getting the (remote) server version as outlined [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036358):

Worklight Server (All Editions)

If the server is up and running, you can find the version with the following steps. Otherwise continue to the next section.

- Ensure your Worklight server is running.
- Open the Worklight Console (http://:/worklight/console).
- Click on the “About" link in the top right corner of the screen.
- A pop-up will display showing the current server version

If the server is not running, you can find the version with the following steps.

- Locate the directory where Worklight Server is installed (example.: C:\IBM\Worklight)
- Navigate to \WorklightServer.
- Open the file "worklight-jee-library.jar" using any archive tool that supports the "zip" format.
- Once the jar is expanded, open the "conf/worklight.properties" file.
- Within that file, the version number is defined by the "build.version" property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I realize that I effectively asked two questions, and you answered one of them. I wish I could accept both!